# Keep or not keep .idea settings in source control?

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

The most inconvenient thing when you work in a team is when you switch between branches (if one of branches has another libs/modules) and settings of `Intellij IDEA` are getting lost because its `.idea` folder is excluded from source control because:

1. Developers are afraid their settings would be rewritten by someone's
   else from a team.
2. Those files from `.idea` folder are constantly
       change so you must include them in literally each commit which
       makes it dirt.

   So it is just unclear how to keep "Project Structure", i.e. libraries/modules dependencies, managed so it is easy thing to switch between branches or setup a project from just cloned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Knowledge Base document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067).

We share projects between a dozen of developers with no issues.

If you switch between branches, it's recommended that `.idea` folder and `.iml` files are added to the source control.